# Generating Bulls and Cows secret word with given n String inputs

Tags: algorithm, logic

I am stuck on this problem for quite a while, it is basically reverse engineering bulls and cow game.
Read more here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows
I am not able to develop a logic for the problem given below, if you can think of a solving approach please comment the same.

Problem Statement:

Given few clue words(of form ABCD/DBCA etc) and the number of cows and bulls for each word,program
should be able to work out the actual word by evaluating the given clue words and generate the output secret word.

TEST CASES:

Input:
4 
DBCC 0 2 
CDAB 2 1 
CAAD 1 2 
CDDA 2 0

Output:
BDAA

Comment: Except the output "BDAA" doesn't follow the rule.  The page you reference says "without duplication" but I see a double-A.  Of course, it just makes the problem harder.

Comment: Oh, I mentioned the reference for Bulls and Cows game in general, anyways duplication would have to be dealt with.

Comment: I think this is more similar to mastermind, since you are allowed duplicates. The algorithms for that should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to reduce the space of possible solutions. Before you start, all 4^4 combinations are possible. After you read the first clue [DBCC 0 2 ], you can eliminate a number of possible solutions, in this particular example you can eliminate all states which have a D in the first place, all which have a B in the second place and so on. Just eliminate all possible solutions which do not "fit" the current clue.

Do this with each clue, until only one solution is left. Another interesting problem of course is how to generate good clue patterns.

Comment: This seems to be a good way of doing it, I am starting with generating the string permutations. Thanks alot!

Comment: Of course elimination of all rows that have Ds in the first column is only first order logic.  You also need to eliminate any states where at least two of the characters are not DBCC.

Comment: Yes, Seth is absolutely right, my answer was not meant to be "complete" in the sense that what I wrote was all that you could infer from that clue, I just wanted to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to deal with a clue of form ABCD 1,2 (1 Bull and 2 Cows) ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is: 
1. Generate all possible words, put them in a list (array)
2. Randomly select one of them (first question)and ask for clues
3. Take the answer (let's say it is 2,1)
4. Start comparing that question with 
first, second, ..., to the last word from the list
5. if they give the same clue: count them, plac